# Create a vector for the week and year

Tags: r

I need to create a vector for the days of the year (1-365) and then assign the days of the week to it starting with Monday. I can do the first part but I can't seem to figure out how to merge the days of the week (Monday,Tuesday...) with it so they repeat for the year when printed:

```
all.days = c(1:365)
days.week = (days=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
"Friday", "Saturday","Sunday")
```

Comment: What about the `year` info?  If it is simply assigning days, then `rep(days, length.out = 365)`

Comment: Ok the golden rule of dealing with dates, is that you don't mess with dates, get yourself some good tseries library like lubridate and ask what is the day of the week, wday()

Comment: ugh, so obvious.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @Bruno - There is nothing wrong with using the multitude of date functions and formatting available in R without packages - `format(seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by="1 day"), "%u")` for instance will give the day of the week starting at Monday (see `?strptime` for all the possible formats).

Answer (score 0):

This gives a vector that is 365 long and starts with Monday and gives successive days of the week. It is based on the fact that 2018-01-01 is a Monday.

```
all.days <- 1:365
format(as.Date("2018-01-01") + all.days - 1, "%A")
```

giving:

```
[1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday" 
[7] "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
[13] "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday" 
... etc ...
```